From RenderTexture to Texture2D: CopyTexture() and ReadPixels() make the texture2d a single color, ignoring the pattern on the original
So, I am trying to create a texture made of random squares in random positions, random sizes and random colors, given a range, with a grey background.
To accomplish this, I have created a method that creates this random pattern by instantiating images on a panel in a canvas. The result is a grey panel with a random pattern of 400 children squares.
Now, I have turned this into a RenderTexture so that I can save this random pattern that is created and can be visually seen in a single item (the rendertexture) instead of 1 panel and 400 children. Then, I delete those 400 children squares so that I have once again a clean background slate and I can start a new cycle, create 400 new children squares, get a new random pattern and possibly save that as well in a different texture.
That's why I need to convert the first RenderTexture into a Texture2D, add this Texture2D to a list, then once I have created a new pattern I will have a different RenderTexture, save it into a new Texture2D, add it to the list and so on...
I have tried to use both ReadPixels() and CopyTexture(), but the resulting Texture2D is a monochrome color instead of the random pattern that I can clearly see on the RenderTexture at runtime. No idea why.
This is the variant with copytexture:
 public Texture2D cachedMask;
 public Camera RenderTexCam;
 public RenderTexture renTex;

 private void Awake()
 {
     cachedMask = new Texture2D(256, 256, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true);
     rend = CFSPanel.GetComponent<Renderer>();
     RenderTexCam.Render();
 }

void Start(){
Graphics.CopyTexture(renTex, cachedMask);
}

This is the variant with readpixels:
public Texture2D FromRenTexToTex2D(RenderTexture RenTex)
{
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(256, 256, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    RenderTexture.active = RenTex;
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, RenTex.width, RenTex.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    return tex;
}

...

cachedMask = FromRenTexToTex2D(renTex);

I have tried to change textureformat, to tinker with initialising values, to tinker with the inspector and public variables, and yet the best result I have reached is this monochrome color instead of a randomized pattern in the Texture2D exactly as shown in the RenderTexture

Are both textures the same size and format (or compatible format)?

As for the size, yes, I even changed the line in Awake: now it is
       cachedMask = new Texture2D(renTex.width, renTex.height);
so they are definitely the same size.
Regarding the format, the texture2d (cachedMask) is automatically RGBA8 sRGB if I don't specify anything, so I tried to change the RenderTexture (renTex) in the inspector, setting it at a sRGB format, which is B8G8R8A8_SRGB.
Is that enough or are they still different?

Ok, there must be something fishy going on maybe with the initialization of some variable, because I tried a different approach: instead of creating the rendertexture as a new asset and set it as a target texture for a new camera gameobject in the scene, I tried to do everything through scripting.
rt = new RenderTexture(800, 400, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
cachedMask = new Texture2D(800, 400, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
RenderTexCam.targetTexture = rt;
RenderTexCam.Render();
Graphics.CopyTexture(rt, cachedMask);
It worked like a charm

Are you sure the render texture asset had the correct resolution? Would probably be better to make your Texture 2D have the same resolution as the render texture..

Graphics.CopyTexture is not appropriate for copying from a RenderTexture to a Texture2D, unless ofc you don't plan to save it to a file. Reason being that a RenderTexture is a GPU-only image, whereas a Texture2D, if readable, has a CPU component as well, which you can modify in until you do Apply which updates the GPU texture.
From the Graphics.CopyTexture docs:

This method copies pixel data from one texture to another on the GPU. If you set Texture.isReadable to true for both src and dst textures, the method also copies pixel data on the CPU.

So, apart from the other requirements of Graphics.CopyTexture, both src and dst need to have a CPU component in order for the copy to work, ie they both need to be Texture2D.
As for the Texture2D.ReadPixels variant, assuming RenTex is actually compatible (same dimensions, similar format), I'd check whether your RenderTexture is correct. Be it with RenderDoc, or just throw it on a shaded material to see if the pattern is actually correctly painted into the RT. For one, you call RenderTexCam.Render(), which I assume renders the pattern to the RenTex, but it's in Awake, which might even be too early for your pattern to be spawned and placed. When do you call this again? Do you listen to keypresses to re-call this function? Because, unless you've carefully set this up, I doubt your pattern is arranged in time for this Awake to render it to a render texture, so the monochrome sounds about right. Additionaly, you'll see in the Texture2D.ReadPixels docs the AsyncGPUReadback.RequestIntoNativeArray is a faster way to do this.
By the way, if you're gonna create a new Texture2D inside FromRenTexToTex2D and return it, you ruin the point of preallocating cachedMask in Awake. Instead you should be using cachedMask directly in FromRenTexToTex2D.
Another thing, when changing RenderTexture.active, you need to cache whatever rt it was referencing before and revert it after you're done with it. Because if you don't revert it to previous state, you might ruin other things as well. RenderTexture.active docs show this practice.

Thanks for the precise reply. Luckily enough, I didn't want to save any texture and I was just trying to create and use them at runtime, so that they would be different everytime I started the program. That's why CopyTexture seemed like the best option.
Anyway, you are right, I messed up with Awake and what I put inside. Two days ago I properly moved the render call after the rendertexture was correctly set up instead of at the beginning, so I was on the right track, after all. Your insights will probably make this easier to understand if I happen to stumble into this problem again!

Yeah, CopyTexture is generally the faster option. ReadPixels or anything else is slower, but they are usually used when you need a readable texture you can mess with from CPU side.
